# How to use approval tests for testing databases?

Tags: c#, approval-tests

I would like to approval-test a result of a database query using classes provided by [ApprovalTests.Net](https://github.com/approvals/ApprovalTests.Net) library. I understand how approval tests work, but could not find a single example on how to use classes from Persistence namespaces. Would appreciate some examples to get me started.

I am refactoring a complex Sql query. I need to make sure that the new version of the query is returning a same resultset after the refactoring. I think I can accomplish it like this:

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.Fill(adapter, connection);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
dataSet.WriteXml(sw);
string result = sw.ToString();
Approvals.Verify(result);
```

But I think there is a better way to do it using classes from [Persistence](https://github.com/approvals/ApprovalTests.Net/tree/master/ApprovalUtilities/Persistence/Database) namespace without explicit conversion of Dataset to xml string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chris made a [screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5gIeJ6z82Pk) about the ILoader pattern with ApprovalTests.